# rails fetching related data in page results

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Supposing I have 3 tables: Users, Roles and UserRoles. I can fetch the user_roles in the request: `users/1/user_roles` but what if I want to fetch the roles of a user such as: `users/1/roles`.

My relation is as follows:

```
has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles
```

Is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The relation in your model has no direct relevance to the url you go to. You need to replicate your existing behaviour for `routes` rather than `user_routes` by either adding a new action or new controller and creating new views etc.

At the moment you probably have either:

- an action called `user_routes` in the `UsersController`
- an action called `index` in the `UserRoutesController`

So either:

- Add an action called `routes` in the `UsersController`
- Add an controller called `RoutesController` with an index action.

Regardless to which method you are using, in your action set your instance variable to `user.roles` instead of `user.user_roles`.

You can then write whatever view code you need.